# unable to apply gpfdist protocol while working with spark

Tags: apache-spark, greenplum

I am trying to read data from greenplum into HDFS using spark. To do that, I am using the jar file: `greenplum-spark_2.11-1.6.0.jar`

Applying spark.read as below:

```
val yearDF = spark.read.format("io.pivotal.greenplum.spark.GreenplumRelationProvider").option("url", "jdbc:postgresql://1.2.3.166:5432/finance?ssl=true&sslfactory=org.postgresql.ssl.NonValidatingFactory").option("server.port","8020").option("dbtable", "tablename").option("dbschema","schema").option("user", "123415").option("password", "etl_123").option("partitionColumn","je_id").option("partitions",3).load().where("period_year=2017 and period_num=12 and source_system_name='SSS'").select(splitSeq map col:_*).withColumn("flagCol", lit(0))
yearDF.write.format("csv").save("hdfs://dev/apps/hive/warehouse/header_test_data/")
```

When I run the above code, I get the exception:

```
Exception in thread "qtp1438055710-505" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
19/03/05 12:29:08 WARN QueuedThreadPool:
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
19/03/05 12:29:08 WARN QueuedThreadPool: Unexpected thread death: org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3@16273740 in qtp1438055710{STARTED,8<=103<=200,i=19,q=0}
19/03/05 12:36:03 ERROR Executor: Exception in task 0.0 in stage 4.0 (TID 8)
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: error when writing data to gpfdist http://1.2.3.8:8020/spark_6ca7d983d07129f2_db5510e67a8a6f78_driver_370, quit after 2 tries (url_curl.c:584)  (seg7 ip-1-3-3-196.ec2.internal:40003 pid=4062) (cdbdisp.c:1322)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2310)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2023)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:217)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.execute(PgStatement.java:421)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeWithFlags(PgStatement.java:318)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeUpdate(PgStatement.java:294)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyStatement.executeUpdate(ProxyStatement.java:120)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyStatement.executeUpdate(HikariProxyStatement.java)
    at io.pivotal.greenplum.spark.jdbc.Jdbc$$anonfun$2.apply(Jdbc.scala:81)
    at io.pivotal.greenplum.spark.jdbc.Jdbc$$anonfun$2.apply(Jdbc.scala:79)
    at resource.AbstractManagedResource$$anonfun$5.apply(AbstractManagedResource.scala:88)
    at scala.util.control.Exception$Catch$$anonfun$either$1.apply(Exception.scala:125)
    at scala.util.control.Exception$Catch$$anonfun$either$1.apply(Exception.scala:125)
    at scala.util.control.Exception$Catch.apply(Exception.scala:103)
    at scala.util.control.Exception$Catch.either(Exception.scala:125)
    at resource.AbstractManagedResource.acquireFor(AbstractManagedResource.scala:88)
    at resource.ManagedResourceOperations$class.apply(ManagedResourceOperations.scala:26)
    at resource.AbstractManagedResource.apply(AbstractManagedResource.scala:50)
    at resource.DeferredExtractableManagedResource$$anonfun$tried$1.apply(AbstractManagedResource.scala:33)
    at scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:192)
    at resource.DeferredExtractableManagedResource.tried(AbstractManagedResource.scala:33)
    at io.pivotal.greenplum.spark.jdbc.Jdbc$.copyTable(Jdbc.scala:83)
    at io.pivotal.greenplum.spark.externaltable.GreenplumRowIterator.liftedTree1$1(GreenplumRowIterator.scala:105)
    at io.pivotal.greenplum.spark.externaltable.GreenplumRowIterator.<init>(GreenplumRowIterator.scala:104)
    at io.pivotal.greenplum.spark.GreenplumRDD.compute(GreenplumRDD.scala:49)
```

I applied the steps just as they were mentioned in this official [documentation](https://greenplum-spark.docs.pivotal.io/160/rw_example.html#lg2s_example_proc)

Earlier I used the jar: `greenplum.jar` which was working fine but was slower as it pulls the data thru GP Master.
The jar: `greenplum-spark_2.11-1.6.0.jar` is a connector jar which uses `gpfdist` protocol to pull the data to HDFS.

Also the IP Addresses is changed in the exception message. You can see the IP `1.2.3.166:5432` become `1.2.3.8:8020` and also `seg7 ip-1-3-3-196.ec2.internal:40003 pid=4062`

With the same number of executors and executor memory, I could retrieve the data using `greenplum.jar`. But keeping everything same and just changed the jar to `greenplum-spark_2.11-1.6.0.jar` only to face this exception.
I have been trying to fix the issue but I don't understand this phenomenon at all.
Could anyone let me know how can I fix this problem ?

Answer (score 0):

Greenplum-Spark connector is designed to parallelize the data transfer between Greenplum segments and Spark workers.  In order to fully utilize the parallel data transfer, you have to provide sufficient memory and spark workers , in order to speed up data transfer. Otherwise, you can use greenplum.jar that uses single JDBC connector to load data from HDFS into Greenplum database via single Greenplum master. It is significantly slower when you are using data loading into single Greenplum master.

Some considerations:
- Depends on number of Greenplum segments, do you have sufficient Spark workers / executors to receive or send data between Spark and Greenplum clusters ?
- Depends on memory allocated to Spark workers/executors. Refers to "[Tuning Spark](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/tuning.html)" document

From the error log with this message "java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded", i can assume that your spark worker/executors are not having sufficient memory.  You still need to tune your Spark workers so it can parallelize data loading from HDFS.

Answer (score 0):

Can you increase the number of partitions? Depending on the size of the table you may need to increase the number of partitions. Can you try increasing the number of partitions to 30 and see if you still run into Out of Memory Issues?

```
val yearDF = spark.read.format("io.pivotal.greenplum.spark.GreenplumRelationProvider").option("url", "jdbc:postgresql://1.2.3.166:5432/finance?ssl=true&sslfactory=org.postgresql.ssl.NonValidatingFactory").option("server.port","8020").option("dbtable", "tablename").option("dbschema","schema").option("user", "123415").option("password", "etl_123").option("partitionColumn","je_id").option("partitions",30).load().where("period_year=2017 and period_num=12 and source_system_name='SSS'").select(splitSeq map col:_*).withColumn("flagCol", lit(0))
yearDF.write.format("csv").save("hdfs://dev/apps/hive/warehouse/header_test_data/")
```

Comment: There are just 2million rows, number of columns in the table are 37. Even if I give a single partition with 4gb memory, spark should handle it. But I don't think I am applying the protocol in the right.

Comment: I don't see anything unusual with the way you are using the protocol. However, the GC overhead limit error does make me think that Spark is having issues with the amount of data. Maybe try 10 partitions `.option("partitions",10)` to see if you are able to overcome the GC issues.